# There is already an object named '#DIR_Cat' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

In my Stored procedure, I have added a command to create a hash temp table #DIR_CAT. But every time I execute the procedure I get this error:
"There is already an object named '#DIR_Cat' in the database."
Even when I have already created an Exists clause at the start of SP to check and drop the table if it is present. Any help is much appreciated.

The code goes like this.

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'#DIR_Cat') )       
drop table #DIR_Cat  
/* some lines of code*/

CREATE TABLE #DIR_Cat (XMLDta xml)  

/* some lines of code*/

INSERT #DIR_Cat exec (@stmt)  

/* some lines of code*/

drop table #DIR_Cat
```

Comment: What database you using? MySQL or Sql Server? You have both tagged

Comment: he is using sql-server

Comment: the temp table should not exists at the begining of the stored procedure. Is the stored procedure execute at it self or being called by another stored procedure ?

Comment: `dbo.sysobjects` refers to the current database it is connected to. Temp tables will be created in `tempdb` no matter where you create it.

Comment: To add more, I have another similar SP, only the file path and a few parameters differ. The use of # temp table is almost same, and in that procedure I don't even have a check if the # table is present or not. But that procedure executes just fine. See below (No exist command used to drop temp table in the beginning)                                                   CREATE TABLE #DIR_Cat_FRA (XMLDta xml)  

/* some lines of code*/

INSERT #DIR_Cat_FRA exec (@stmt)  

/* some lines of code*/

drop table #DIR_Cat_FRA

Answer (score 1):

Main issue is you're not fully qualifying your objects. Your temp table lives in tempdb, whereas the system views use whatever database you're currently connected to by default. So essentially you're looking for the temp table, but you're looking in whatever database your currently connected to (which I'm guessing is not tempdb).

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server here, although you did also mention mysql in the tags. If that's what you're using, this code may not apply.

Here's the snippet I use for temp table drop/create

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#<TableName, sysname, >') is not null drop table #<TableName, sysname, >
create table #<TableName, sysname, >
(


)
```

Side note, don't use `dbo.sysobjects`. That's a really old compatibility view. If you want to use objects, use `sys.objects` instead.

Comment: Side side note: Seeing lots of folks dropping temp tables at the end of a stored proc. Unnecessary and in a high-transaction system (500-1000/sec) i've experienced slowdowns. (MSFT told me to stop). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. temp table does not exists in local DB sys.objects, it is in tempdb

you need to query `tempb.sys.objects`

2. the `name` of the temp table does not appear exactly as it is in the `tempdb.sys.objects`.

You can't query it just like

```
select * 
from   tempdb.sys.objects
where  name = '#DIR_Cat'  -- This does not works
```

you need to use `object_id()`

```
select * 
from   tempdb.sys.objects
where  object_id = object_id('tempdb..#DIR_Cat')
```